# Names of vectors in list

Tags: r, lapply

I have list of vectors of same length and I'm looking for some easy way how to name elements of the vectors. I can do it by using for-loop like this:

```
myList <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
for (i in 1:3){ names(myList[[i]]) <- c("a", "b", "c") }
```

Is there any way to do this e.g. with lapply or another more elegant way?

I tried it with this code:

```
lapply(names(myList), function(i) names(myList[[i]])<- c("a", "b", "c"))
```

But this one only gives me new list of names, not names my current list.

Comment: Maybe ```lapply(myList, `names<-`, letters[1:3])```?

Comment: If the vectors are not just the same lengths, but also the same types, then maybe a list is not the best structure to begin with...

Comment: Thank you, David, this one works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
lapply(myList, setNames, letters[1:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
lapply(myList, function(x) { names(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c'); x})
```